# What is the colloquial/comman usage of '棒'

Tags: vocabulary, word

I have seen it as usage of 很棒, but I don't get how that means thumbs up as it were?  Was I misunderstanding the comment on the video??

I know that on mdbg.net there is a different meaningg = = ~~~~ : )

It says:  stick / club / cudgel / smart / capable / strong / wonderful / classifier for legs of a relay race

Whenever I search it on Google images, it only shows thumbs up..O_O

I seen this on a video about 楚辞, I think it is worth a share :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlkBPOX2u7I

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://www.zhihu.com/question/41619434) which have over 600 people voted to agree

> *木棒的“棒”，乃是强盛的木*
>
> '棒' (rod) is 'strong hard wood'
>
> *你说一个人“棒势”，那么就是说他屌大*
>
> When you say someone "rob form" , it means he has "huge penis"

棒 means 'baton / rod',  which is 'stiff and hard'

The term “好棒" was originally a slang for '**excellent**, **great**, **wonderful**' -- meaning something is as great as a 'good hard rod' (hard rod is a metaphor for stiff penis)

Answer (score 1):

It means : You did a good job. Or well done. If I solved a problem for you, you can say "棒" to me.